# custom view with objects on screens with different screensize and pixel density

Tags: android, pixel, screen-resolution

I would like to draw a circle in my custom view and it should appear nearly the same size on any screenresolution and density.

for example if I would draw the circle with a radius of 50 pixel, then it appears large on a screen with low resolution. But on a high resolution screen it appears small.

My first try was to simply calculate the size depending on the screensize. BUT on a small device with a very high resolution the circle looks too small. 
I guess I can't manage the pixeldensity.

How would you solve my problem ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access screen density via `DisplayMetrics` as described here [How to define a pixel independent height in an onDraw() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028433/how-to-define-a-pixel-independant-height-in-an-ondraw-method)